# TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class. Why?

Tags: python

Why is python writing me this error 'TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Person with abstract method introduce_yourself'?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Person(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name=name

    @abstractmethod
    def introduce_yourself(self):
        pass

adam = Person('Adam')
```

Comment: If you want to instantiate it why _is_ it abstract? You define no implementations that actually have the method.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you called `adam.introduce_yourself()`?

Comment: I just didn't know that I can't call function which is defined like abstractmethod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are encountering is occurring because you are trying to create an instance of the Person class, which is defined as an abstract class. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated directly, meaning you cannot create objects of abstract classes. Subclasses must implement any abstract methods defined in the abstract class.

Example

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Person(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name=name

    @abstractmethod
    def introduce_yourself(self):
        pass

class SubPerson(Person):

    def introduce_yourself(self):
        print("myself")

adam = SubPerson('Adam')
```